# Set hosting environment variables in Mac using vnext (ASP.NET 5 RC1 Update1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working in my web app in Windows and Mac. In Windows with VS2015 Community I can change the environment variables using the VS2015 (properties web project).

In Mac, I have tested with the command **export** but when I exit of the terminal, the environment variable is deleted.

```
export ASPNET_ENV="Development"
```

When I start the project in Mac, I see:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

How can I change the Hosting Environment? And How can I add more permanents variables? Thanks!!

Comment: Isn't `ASP_NET` supposed to be `ASPNET_ENV` instead? That's how I see it in Windows at least.

Comment: Yes, edited, sorry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running export from a terminal, the export is only good for that session.  For the variable to be seen by things outside of that session, you should export the variable in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks, I have done it, and It works... more help here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables