# Set custom environments variables in Mac using ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have done [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338977/set-hosting-environment-variables-in-mac-using-vnext-asp-net-5-rc1-update1/34339170#34339170) and solved my first problem.

But now, I have another question...

What is the correct way to create **custom** Environment Variables? If I try to create for example AppSettings:ConnectionString environment variable, I have this error:

> -bash: export: `AppSettings:ConnectionString ': not a valid identifier

Thanks...

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, please do not forget to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `:` by `__`

So `AppSettings:ConnectionString` becomes `AppSettings__ConnectionString`

Quote from source:

> To override nested keys through environment variables in shells that don’t support : in variable names replace them with __ (double underscore).

[Source](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-the-built-in-providers)